# Why canvas is not the size that I declared it

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas, drawing

I want to create a canvas where I have a pie chart but I get larger size than what I want.

As we can see here the canvas is `1000px*1000px` although I have declared it `200px*200px`.

How do I make my pie chart be `200*200`? What do I need to change?

```
<div>
  <canvas id="timeSpentChart" width="200" height="200">
<div>
```

[image]

As seen in the screenshot the inspect show me different code than what I actually wrote, why is that happening?

This is the code for the pie chart:

```
<script>
    // Retrieve the data for the time spent and money spent in each section
    var timeSpentData = <?php echo json_encode($sections_array); ?>;

    // Get the canvas elements
    var timeSpentCanvas = document.getElementById("timeSpentChart");

    // Create the time spent pie chart
    var timeSpentChart = new Chart(timeSpentCanvas, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: timeSpentData.map(section => section.section_id),
            datasets: [{
                data: timeSpentData.map(section => section.time_spent),
                backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange'], // Add more colors if needed
            }]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Time Spent in Each Section'
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Anyone know how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The actual size of the canvas can be determined using the `width` and `height` attributes. **The displayed size, on the other hand, is defined using the width and height properties within the `style` attribute.**

#### Example

The drawing size will be 1000px (by width) x 1000px (by height). The displayed size, on the other hand, will be 200px (by style.width) x 200px (by style.height) based on the style.

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="timeSpentChart" width="1000" height="1000" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

#### Summary

The larger the drawing size, the more pixels the canvas will consist of. Using the style attribute, similar to any other HTML element, we can only set the display dimensions of the rendered canvas. Therefore, in many cases, it is pointless to set a larger drawing size than its display size.

Comment: This still doesn't make my canvas 200*200

Comment: My question is: Why is it bigger than what I have declared? and How do I make it the desired size?

Comment: As clearly visible in your photo, you have set the drawing size to 666x666 while the display size to 1000x1000. Therefore, the displayed canvas of 1000x1000 is correct based on your settings. I don't understand where he declared the width of 200x200 in his own code if it's not reflected in the HTML code. Perhaps he overwrote it in JavaScript?

Comment: `How do I make my pie chart be 200*200? What do I need to change?` --- If follow my code... then... `style="height: 200px; width: 200px;"` ---- but again I note that your attached photo does not reflect the attached code

Comment: Yes I agree with you. And that is what I do not understand as well. I have declared it correctly but after that for some reason there are changes and extra things that I have not added. Could it be because of the chart?

Comment: if you try resize chart.js generated canvas: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html --- myChart.canvas.parentNode.style (.height and .width) or myChart.resize(height, width)